# catkin_make doesn't find all the targets

Tags: gazebo, catkin-make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I run catkin_make, it gives the following output:

```
Base path: /home/ben/workspaces/ROS/smf1
Source space: /home/ben/workspaces/ROS/smf1/src
Build space: /home/ben/workspaces/ROS/smf1/build
Devel space: /home/ben/workspaces/ROS/smf1/devel
Install space: /home/ben/workspaces/ROS/smf1/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/ben/workspaces/ROS/smf1/build"
####
####
#### Running command: "make -j4 -l4" in "/home/ben/workspaces/ROS/smf1/build"
####
Built target smf1_gazebo_pkg_xacro_generated_to_devel_space_
```

I don't know what "smf1_gazebo_pkg_xacro_generated_to_devel_space_" is. I have a package called simply "smf1_gazebo_pkg". It uses xacro. catkin_make works fine in my other workspaces, and I don't see a difference in the CMakeLists.txt files. It doesn't seem to find any .xacro files or .gazebo files. The CMakeLists.txt file for the package smf1_gazebo_pkg is this:

```
       cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
        project(smf1_gazebo_pkg)
        
        ## Find catkin macros and libraries
        ## if COMPONENTS list like find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS xyz)
        ## is used, also find other catkin packages
        find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
          geometry_msgs
          roscpp
          rviz
          tf
          urdf
          xacro
        )
include_directories(
      ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    )
```

The CMakeLists.txt has the same thing for a sub package, but specifies its name, mybot_description, and also has install(DIRECTORY urdf DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}).

Here is what I get from running  tree -L 3 ~/workspaces/ROS/smf1/src   There should be files under urdf. That's where all the .xacro and .gazebo files are at. Also, the project runs. When I roslaunch the mybot_world.launch file, gazebo comes up and my robot appears. Changes don't reflect though, obviously. I'm getting really confussed.

```
├── CMakeLists.txt -> /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/toplevel.cmake
└── smf1_gazebo_pkg
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── include
    │   └── smf1_gazebo_pkg
    ├── launch
    │   └── mybot_world.launch
    ├── mybot_control
    │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
    │   ├── config
    │   ├── launch
    │   └── package.xml
    ├── mybot_description
    │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
    │   ├── package.xml
    │   └── urdf
    ├── mybot.rviz
    ├── package.xml
    ├── src
    └── worlds
        └── mybot.world
```

Does anyone have any ideas about this? Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/279076/catkin_make-doesn%27t-find-all-the-targets/) by [horseatinweeds](https://answers.ros.org/users/33178/horseatinweeds/) on ROS Answers with karma: 160 on 2018-01-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2018-01-08**:
Well, I'm not sure what your problem is, but it seems you have nested ROS packages. The `CMakeLists.txt` you posted is from your `mybot_description` package...

**Comment by [horseatinweeds](https://answers.ros.org/users/33178/horseatinweeds/) on 2018-01-08**:
Does catkin_make find nested packages? A number of tutorials I've been following have them nested, unless I'm misunderstanding. I'm still trying to understand how packages are are intended to be organized in ROS.

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2018-01-08**:
It might work, but is not good practice. You can have pacakges in subdirectories, but they should not be nested, IMO.

**Comment by [horseatinweeds](https://answers.ros.org/users/33178/horseatinweeds/) on 2018-01-08**:
OK. I think that's my mistake. I'll reorganize and give it another try. Thanks.

**Comment by [horseatinweeds](https://answers.ros.org/users/33178/horseatinweeds/) on 2018-01-08**:
This is what has me so confused: https://github.com/LTU-AutoEV/mybot_gazebo_tutorial  It has a package mybot_gazebo, inside of which there are two packages, mybot_control and mybot_description. Is this correct?

**Comment by [horseatinweeds](https://answers.ros.org/users/33178/horseatinweeds/) on 2018-01-08**:
Actually, try this link: https://github.com/HumaRobotics/mybot_gazebo_tutorial

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2018-01-09**:
Wow, I'm surprised there are no Errors (I can reproduce that)... Catkin packages need to be unique inside a workspace...
Seems it does not detect nested work packages then.

The recommended layout is [here](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0128.html#recommended-layout).

But I can't reproduce your issue

**Comment by [horseatinweeds](https://answers.ros.org/users/33178/horseatinweeds/) on 2018-01-10**:
I found the issue. ROS was finding the package in a separate workspace. I renamed the packages and put them just inside src and everything started working... All except join friction doesn't seem to work. Thanks mig.

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2018-01-11**:
@horseatinweeds, would be great if you could answer yourself with the solution and accept this answer as correct. Could help further users with the same issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The main issue was that ROS was finding my packages in another workspace. I renamed the packages and the changes worked.

---

Originally posted by [horseatinweeds](https://answers.ros.org/users/33178/horseatinweeds/) with karma: 160 on 2018-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0